# PHP зависает на на одном из файлов

Tags: php, php-fpm, vesta

Есть такой код :

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../creds.php';
use MonologPHPMailer\PHPMailerHandler;

use Monolog\Formatter\HtmlFormatter;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Processor\IntrospectionProcessor;
use Monolog\Processor\MemoryUsageProcessor;
use Monolog\Processor\WebProcessor;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

$mailer = new PHPMailer(true);
$logger = new Logger('logger');

$mailer->isSMTP();
$mailer->Host = $STMPHost;
$mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$mailer->Username = $STMPUsername;
$mailer->Password = $STMPPassword;

$mailer->setFrom($STMPUsername, 'Logging Server');
$mailer->addAddress('okv23200@gmail.com', 'Dear developer!');

$logger->pushProcessor(new IntrospectionProcessor);
$logger->pushProcessor(new MemoryUsageProcessor);
$logger->pushProcessor(new WebProcessor);

$handler = new PHPMailerHandler($mailer);
$handler->setFormatter(new HtmlFormatter);

$logger->pushHandler($handler);

$logger->error('Error!');
$logger->alert('Something went wrong!');
echo "fdsgdsgdhbsdf";
?>
```

PHP на этом файле зависает намертво ни ошибок ничего. При запуске на сервере Nginx пишет акое в логи :

```
24 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,
```

Comment: добавьте логирование каждой строки и посмотрите, где именно зависает

Comment: Зависает на 36 строчке а если закомментировать то на следующей

Comment: Теперь мы должны угадать где у вас 35 строка?

Comment: $logger->error('Error!'); и $logger->alert('Something went wrong!');

Comment: Значит у вас ошибка в классе `Logger`. Смотрите, что делают методы `error` и `alert`

Comment: не думаю что проблема с этим классом. Во-первых это монолог какие еще ошибки ? Во-вторых Протестировал еще один скрипт ничего не зависает.

Comment: Так таймаут же, надо больше времени дать на обработк скрипта. МОжет много данных? Иногда такое бывает, когда скрипт отправляет запрос на сторонний хост, а тот не отвечает. ПРи этом нет try catch и нет исключения.

Comment: А вы уверены, что подключение к почтовому ящику проходит?

Comment: Если бы не проходило подключение к ящику была-бы ошибка. На счёт большого кол-ва данных сейчас проверю

Comment: Время исполнения увеличил до 90 не помогло. А данных через POST или GET вообще не поступает. Так-что проблема не в этом